# Problems converting a python pygame into exe

Tags: python, pygame, exe, file-conversion

okay so I'm trying to convert my python `pygame` game into a `.exe` file so I can send it to friends but every time I try to convert it creates the `.exe` file but I can't open it doesn't mark any error and it doesn't have any extra files

I have tried `auto-py-to-exe` and `pyinstaller` almost every possible combination

it only uses `pygame`, `Sys` and `random` modules and python of curse
[here is a GitHub with the file](https://github.com/hiiiiiiiiiiih/pygame-gmae.git)

I don't know if you can tell me how to convert it or just straight upconvert it for me

Comment: not sure how to convert sorry, but just played your game haha. I made one like it a couple years ago, a good one for getting started with python. ill try find out how to convert it to exe.

Comment: thx it was really fun creating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get py2exe. It is easy to use. Assuming your main script is game.py and that script includes all the other stuff, all you need to do is prepare yet another script, let us call it setup.py and type in:

> from distutils.core import setup  import py2exe
> setup(console=['game.py'])

Now execute that file and it compiles everything into an executable:

> python setup.py py2exe

Comment: do i have to saveit in the same carpet as the file

Comment: i execute it in the cmd of the carpet